# SQL SERVER - sum over partition by distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

```
 rN         rD          rnc      d     expectedResult
abc1m      2010-03-31   abc     5.7    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
abc3m      2010-03-31   abc     5.7    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
abc1y      2010-03-31   abc     5.7    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
xfx1m      2010-03-31   xfx     1.7    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
xfx3m      2010-03-31   xfx     1.7    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
xfx1y      2010-03-31   xfx     1.7    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
tnt1m      2010-03-31   tnt     9.6    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
tnt3m      2010-03-31   tnt     9.6    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
tnt1y      2010-03-31   tnt     9.6    5.7 + 1.7 +9.6
------------------------------------
abc1m      2010-04-01   abc     2.2    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
abc3m      2010-04-01   abc     2.2    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
abc1y      2010-04-01   abc     2.2    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
xfx1m      2010-04-01   xfx     8.9    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
xfx3m      2010-04-01   xfx     8.9    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
xfx1y      2010-04-01   xfx     8.9    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
tnt1m      2010-04-01   tnt     5.5    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
tnt3m      2010-04-01   tnt     5.5    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
tnt1y      2010-04-01   tnt     5.5    2.2 + 8.9 + 5.5
```

**expected result** is the sum of distinct rnc for a specific date 
How to achieve this.
I would like to use something like the code below but doesn't work.

```
select *,
sum (d) over (partition by rD, distinct rnc) as expectedResult
from myTable
where ...--some condition
order by ...--order by some columns
```

Using SQL Server 2012, thanks

**edit:** Regarding the question being on hold, how is this unclear. IF one is only looking at the column `expectedResult` isn't it quite clear? What should I add in order to make it better?
--And every rnc has d. Just assume every set is of the form given in the example. (answering one comment)

Comment: Looking at your data, last 2 chars from rN column can be used for grouping by ... are those chars always repeatable like that (1m, 3m, 1y) in all of RNC or it's coincidence?

Comment: always repeatable . and the column rnc just trimms rN

Comment: Well in that case you can just do Select Right(rN,3), SUM(d) from myTable group by Right(rN,3) and youll get what you want

Comment: I can't use this. Because I want to `select *` and can't use group by 1,2 columns when i'm selecting a bigger number of columns

Comment: Gimme few min to write it down ...

Comment: great. thanks, looking at it for 1 h now and can't figure it out. I still think the window function over partition by is the way to go. And on msdn it says that i could use `distinct` with `over (partition by someCol)` , but I don't know how exactly. resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

Comment: sum (d) on distinct rnc?  What if every rnc did not have the d?  First define what it is you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As last 2 chars for first column is repeatable, and you are actually summing in partition by that, give it a go and let me know if that's what you asked for

```
create table #TempTable (rn nvarchar(10), rD date, rnc nvarchar(10), d decimal(5,2))

insert into #TempTable (rn, rD, rnc, d)
values
('abc1m','2010-03-31','abc',     5.7),
('abc3m','2010-03-31','abc',     5.7),
('abc1y','2010-03-31','abc',     5.7),
('xfx1m','2010-03-31','xfx',     1.7),
('xfx3m','2010-03-31','xfx',     1.7),
('xfx1y','2010-03-31','xfx',     1.7),
('tnt1m','2010-03-31','tnt',     9.6),
('tnt3m','2010-03-31','tnt',     9.6),
('tnt1y','2010-03-31','tnt',     9.6),
------------------------------------
('abc1m','2010-04-01','abc',     2.2),
('abc3m','2010-04-01','abc',     2.2),
('abc1y','2010-04-01','abc',     2.2),
('xfx1m','2010-04-01','xfx',     8.9),
('xfx3m','2010-04-01','xfx',     8.9),
('xfx1y','2010-04-01','xfx',     8.9),
('tnt1m','2010-04-01','tnt',     5.5),
('tnt3m','2010-04-01','tnt',     5.5),
('tnt1y','2010-04-01','tnt',     5.5)

select rn, rD, rnc, d, SUM(d) over (partition by right(rn,2), rD) as 'Sum' 
from #TempTable
order by Rd
```

Comment: can I avoid grup by? Cause i gave this as an example, but in reality i am having 20 columns and then I have to mention all of them in the select + group by. Thanks for the answer btw. Also why do you do right(rN,2) when you already have that done in rnc

Comment: When ever you are doing any aggregate function you have to have group by

Comment: not if I'm using window-functions as in `over (partition-by)`

Comment: Sorry, had to be away for sometime ... i fixed query so you don't use group by ... and reason why im going right(RN,2) is because in rnc i have Left(rn,3) ... I am using last 2 chars of rn and doing the sum over by that and date ... it should work now

Comment: Sorry for not replaying for a number of days. Didn't have access to test the solution. Clever usage of right(rn,2), dindn't think of that. Your solution is the simplest of everything proposed here.

Comment: just realised that i have a problem. As I formulated the problem , your answer is great and works. But what if i am having a rN of form `abc10y` then `right(rn,2)` won't work, will it? (and it doesn't :( ) any idea? I could write a case, I guess

Comment: Yeah that can work ... basicly i formed a solution based on your given problem ... but you can always change it to do exactly what you need ... I am not aware of which combination of letter you have in RN column, if you gonna have abc10y .. i guess you can go with case checking LEN(RN) and take right(rn,3)

Comment: great. Just my thought too, Will figure something out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here we use cte to group rows that are the same together.
This way, we can sum only the first row of each group in the select.

```
;WITH cte 
AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            GroupRowIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rateDate, rnc, d ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM myTable
)

SELECT  *,
        expectedResult = SUM(d) OVER (PARTITION BY rateDate)
FROM cte
WHERE GroupRowIndex = 1
AND ...--some condition
ORDER BY ...--order by some columns
```

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work as i wanted. Looks like it's calculating like this: `5.7 + 5.7 +5.7` as `Expected result `, then `1.7+1.7+1.7` . It has to take a distinct rnc value (since they are the same for the same date)

Comment: please see the `expectedResult`

Comment: @CM2k, I edited my answer

Comment: saw. tried. getting:  `The function 'ROW_NUMBER' takes exactly 0 argument(s).`

Comment: My bad, try ROW_NUMBER() instead of ROW_NUMBER(D)

Comment: the query works but i don't think it works correctly. Don't have any more time to verify now cause i have to leave. Will access the server on tuesday and will verify your solution in depth. Thanks. You have my upvote cause you gave me a good idea

Comment: Went with another solution as the accepted answer because it was simple and worked , but thank you. Your solution made me google `cte` and now I understand how it works. So, you have my upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross apply to apply the sum of distinct rnc values based on rD

```
SELECT  t1.*, ca.expectedResult
FROM    myTable t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(d) expectedResult 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT rnc, d 
          FROM myTable t2 
          WHERE t2.rd = t1.rd) AS s) ca
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8dc2/1)

Comment: didn't consider `cross apply` , thank you, you gave me a good insight for the future on how I could use this. I went with another solution because that one was the most simple way in which I achieved the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Easy if you don't want to be fancy

- first you need a table of the distinct rD, rnd and d values
- then you need to sum those values
- Then join those back to your original table

.

```
select rN, rD, rnc, d, sub.dsum as expectedResult
from yourtable
join (
  select rD, rnd, sum(d) as dsum 
  from (select distinct rD, rnd, d
      from yourtable
  ) x
  group by rD, rnd
) sub on yourtable.rD = sub.rD and yourtable.rnd = sub.rnd
```